# I get index.php html in firebug console

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I have ext js panel component that when submited it throws js error in firebug console.
I says

```
 'You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <html>

         ... index.php html code here

  </html><!-- use login javascript file --> <!--<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://localhost:9808/recorder/js/login.js"></script>--> 
   <script type="text/javascript">      
        login = true; 
   </script> 
   <div id="login_window"> </div>' when calling method: 
        [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]
```

Intersting is that the html code get concatenated with some additinal html after the "html" tag. and I get index.php html code instead of json. As far as I knwo check() function I call ecoes only json data.

My component code is like this

```
     login_group_combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',
   {
    name: 'combo_name',
    id: 'combo_id',
    fieldLabel: text_label,
    editable: false,
    //possible view options
    store: [
    ],
    listeners:
    {
        focus: function(elem, e)
        {
                function1();
        }
    }
});
```

function1() look like this

```
   function function1(){
      form1.submit({
         url: './index.php/mypage/check',
         success: function(f,a){
             // some code here
             echo json_encode($result_array);
         },
         failure: function(form, action){
            switch (action.failureType) {
               case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Invalid data entered!');
                    break;
               case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                   break;
               case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                  Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
             }
          }
      });
   }
```

The intersting thing is that the execution enters function1(); but doesnt enter form1, success or neither faulire blocks. What could be the problem?

Comment: There are some closing bracket missing in your code

Comment: I cheked for missing brackets, you mean the one at form_check_user(). No, it is not the problem. I checked my code again, I use Aptana. It will tell If I have missing brackets.

Comment: Why it dumps whole index.php html code instead of json.

Comment: Are you using a framework on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load ./index.php/mypage/check in your browser and view source, do you see json or html? Often something in the server framework is putting in the html via header and footer layout code or similiar and some config needs to be set so you can return raw json strings.